# Python Encoding Issues

Tags: python, encoding, binary, decoding

I have data that I would like to decode from and its in Windows-1252 basically I send code to a socket and it sends it back and I have to decode the message and use IEEE-754 to get a certain value from it but I can seem to figure out all this encoding stuff. Here is my code.

```
def printKinds ():
    test = "x40\x39\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9A"

    print (byt1Hex(test))
    test = byt1Hex(test).replace(' ', '')
    struct.unpack('<d', binascii.unhexlify(test))
    print (test)
printKinds()

def byt1Hex( bytStr ):
    return ' '.join( [ "%02X" % ord( x ) for x in bytStr ] )
```

So I use that and then I have to get the value from that.. But it's not working and I can not figure out why.

The current output I am getting is

```
struct.unpack('<d', binascii.unhexlify(data))
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

That the error the expected output I am looking for is **25.1**
but when I encode it, It actually changes the string into the wrong values so when I do this:

```
 print (byt1Hex(data))
```

I expect to get this.

```
40 39 19 99 99 99 99 9A
```

But I actually get this instead

```
78 34 30 39 19 99 99 99 99 9A
```

Comment: Provide some code we can actually run. Show us the byt1Hex function.

Comment: What is not working? What is expected output? What is actual output? What does `byt1Hex` do?

Comment: There is little sense to interpret cp1252 encoded text as IEEE-754 double value: `struct.unpack('!d', 'abcdefgh'.encode('cp1252'))`

Comment: why do you convert a bytestring into hexstring, only to convert it back immediately?

Comment: Im not sure I am new to this stuff and basically my process to this was to get the data decode it, then use IEEE-754 to convert it

Comment: What's encoded in your string? `binary64` or `decimal64` or a combination of smaller values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('!d', 25.1)
b'@9\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a'
>>> struct.unpack('!d', _) #NOTE: no need to call byt1hex, unhexlify
(25.1,)
```

You send, receive bytes over the network. No need hexlify/unhexlify them; unless the protocol requires it (you should mention the protocol in the question then).

Comment: But I get the data "\x40\x39\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9A" from the host and it looks like you changed it?

Comment: @BSD_: it is the same thing: `b"@" == b"\x40"` (if you are on Python 2 then you won't see `b` prefix for bytes literals)

Comment: Uhm, im not sure to be honest how could you tell?

Comment: @BSD_: what are you unsure of? What can I tell?

Comment: Im unsure if im decimal or binary haha thats why I asked you

Comment: `b"\x40\x39\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9A"` is a sequence of bytes that represent `25.1` floating point value  in [IEEE 754 format (binary64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: Yes. just like b'@Rs33333' represents 73.8 floating point value in IEEE 754 format (binary64)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
test = "x40\x39\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9A"
```

You need:

```
test = "\x40\x39\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9A"
```